# How to vary an object's name in a Python 3 loop?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, while-loop, calculator

I'm trying to create a simple calculator, and I need to vary what my object's name is in a loop.

```
RoR = RoR + 1
"C{0}R{1}".format(CoC, RoR) = int(input("What is your row {0} Column {1} number?: ".format(RoR, CoC)))
```

This is what I tried, and it did not work. I want the objects to look like C1R1 = 18 C1R2 = 88 etc. I'm not very good at Python, so some help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the names of objects dynamically? Use a dict.

Comment: If I had any idea about what that was I would. Guess I'll go Google then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary as mentioned in Woobles comment!

```
mydict = {
           'a' : 1,
           'b' : 2,
          ...
         }
```

It's easy to extract/modify the data of 'a' in 'mydict' :

```
>>>print( mydict['a'] )
1
>>>mydict['a'] = 2
>>>print( mydict['a'] )
2
```

So in your case it would be something like:

```
mydict = {}
RoR = RoR + 1

mydict["C{0}R{1}".format(CoC, RoR)] = int(input("What is your row {0} Column {1} number?:  ".format(RoR, CoC)))
```